# How can I share my Ethernet connection over Wi-Fi on OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, mac, connection-sharing

I am trying to share my Mac mini's ethernet connection over my wireless adapter (internal), with no success.

I know about sharing in settings but if I try to share connection with sharing below Mac Settings, it said that I can't because the Internet connection I use is protected by 802.1x and it suggests that I choose another network.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Do not do this. The fact that your network is protected with 802.1X tells me that it's supposed to be a high-security network, with carefully controlled access. Allowing access to this network via a wireless connection will create a security hole unless it's properly integrated into the 802.1X system. If you need wireless access to the network, talk to the people in charge of the network and have them set up a proper, secure, base station. If they can't or won't do this DO NOT TRY TO DO IT YOURSELF BECAUSE YOU WILL BREAK THE NETWORK"S SECURITY.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I know, what you say is right. But this don't work even with my WEP at home (I try for experiment) and the network is my university network, where I access with my credentials, so if I compromise the network, even if I don't think is possible, the admin know who has been. But the problem is that: in my room, at university, there is not Wi-Fi conn. and my mobile can't call without because my mobile can't have 2G/3G/hsdpa signal :/ this is my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to share 802.1X wireless connection by creating a VPN connection on my Mac, then shared internet access from this VPN connection. I think that is the only solution that you can fid for this.

[image]

Comment: Jeffrey, please stop adding links to your website to your posts. They are absolutely irrelevant there. You're free to link to your page [from your profile](http://superuser.com/users/415062/jeffrey-crockett), but if you add the link to all of your posts, your account *will* be suspended for spamming. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Can you ellaborate more on this solution? How do we set this up? There are several different types of VPN on Mac OS X and all have different settings. Which one should we use?